# Create an Amazon web services for iOS

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services

I'm new to AWS and I'd like to know if there is a step by step tutorial on how to create a web services in AWS for iOS. Thanks.

Comment: You want to create iOS client for Amazone web service?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want to create a client application for Amazon Web Services in iOS. Amazon provides an SDK for iOS and also a sample project, you can follow that, here is the [link](http://aws.amazon.com/developers/getting-started/ios/) .
For getting started with AWS and iOS follow this [link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforios/gsg/Welcome.html) .

Comment: I want to create a iOS client to communicate with AWS. Thanks. I'll look into your hyperlink.

Comment: Does that mean I can create web service as normal. For example, using php code to access database and return json data back to request? Or I can use some AWS API ?

Comment: IT depends on your requirement..! And yes you can write your own web service by using php, json and mysql database. Buy some hosting and deploy your web service there. After that you can access it from any client even with iOS.

Comment: Are there any AWS API to help to build web services easier ? For example, to build user authentication web services, etc.

Comment: If you want authentication to access some resource you can see this http://aws.amazon.com/iam/